# QT разбиение проекта на несколько файлов

Tags: c++, qt

Упростил код, дабы было легче разобраться с проблемой.
Имеется класс, описанный в mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void Menu1();
    void NZER_N_B(int &n);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Функция NZER_N_B(int &n) должна быть реализована в отдельном .cpp файле ее вызов осуществляется в главном файле.

nzer_n_b.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

void MainWindow::NZER_N_B(int &n)
{   
   n = 1770;
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pb1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(Menu1()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::Menu1()
{
    int n;
    NZER_N_B(n);

}
```

Но при такой реализации появляются ошибки LNK1120,2001,2019 (ссылка на неразрешенный элемент). Но если написать реализацию этой функции в заголовочном файле и соответственно подключить его. То ошибок нет, но так не правильно, насколько я знаю. Так вот, вопрос как засунуть реализацию кода в cpp и чтобы ошибок не возникало?

Comment: писать реализацию функции в h файле - это нормально (конечно, ситуации бывают разные  и иногда это не нормально). Покажите весь проект, который не компилируется и думаю, Вам предложат решение.

Comment: А вы вновь созданный cpp-файл к проекту подключить не позабыли ли?

Comment: в файле test.pro они подключены:                                            SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    nzer_n_b.cpp

Comment: @ДмитрийСубботин Как минимум вы забыли ее заинклудить. А зачем вам ф-ция класса, если она не использует ничего из this??? Может объявить ее просто как функцию?

Comment: @Sublihim "Как минимум вы забыли ее заинклудить" - можно на счет этого поподробнее, пожалуйста. Просто в qt я работаю впервые. В MCVS можно было объявить функции в заголовочном файле и просто написать реализацию хоть в 10 cpp. Функция класса нужна, так как код далее будет дописываться. Этот пример чисто что бы разобраться

Comment: @ДмитрийСубботин дело же не конкретно в qt или MSVC. Это же С++. Директива `include` просто указывает на то, что в данном месте препроцессор заменит эту директиву, на код из данного файла. Соответственно, в том месте, где вы хотите видеть свою ф-цию вы и вставляете `#include"nzer_n_b.cpp"` В самом `nzer_n_b.cpp` тогда излишне инклудить хидер от mainwindow. Во-вторых, разбиение реализации на несколько cpp - есть не очень хороший тон разработки.

Comment: @Sublihim, спасибо, теперь все работает!

Comment: @ДмитрийСубботин написал ответ, к вашему вопросу. Если действительно - помогло, в вашем случае, то отметьте, пожалуйста впрос, как решенный.

Answer (score 1):

Надо понимать, как работает препроцессор. Когда он встречает директиву `#include`, он просто заменяет ее на код из указанного файла.
Поэтому, если уж вам очень захотелось реализацию разбить на несколько пару файлов, то вам надо сделать следующее:

nzer_n_b.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::NZER_N_B(int &n)
{   
   n = 1770;
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pb1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(Menu1()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

// Можно и вначале файла, под всеми другими #include
// но тут, просто, для примера
#include "nzer_n_b.cpp"

void MainWindow::Menu1()
{
    int n;
    NZER_N_B(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если все именно так как описано в примере, то проблем возникнуть не должно. Возможно после добавления файла не был вызван qmake для перегенерации Makefile'ов. Тогда нужно вызвать qmake из контектстного меню проекта, и пересобрать проект.